# Getting a list of all text that needs to be translated using Yii2 DbMessageSource

Tags: php, yii2, internationalization

I am using Yii2 to work on a project that needs to be translated into various languages. I am using the advanced template and set up my common/main.php like so

```
return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'language' => 'en',
    'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
    'components' => [
        'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                'app' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\DbMessageSource',
                    'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
    ],
    'as beforeRequest' => [
        'class' => 'common\components\CheckLanguage',
    ],
];
```

I have added the required database tables source_message and message. Now each text in the website that I need to have translated I use the Yii::t($category,$message) function.

My question is; How can I get a list of all text in my website that needs to be translated into the database? Do I have to manually scan my site for all Yii::t($category,$message) function calls?

Thanks in advance for your time and input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is console command provided for this scan functionality.

```
./yii message
```

See the documentation in the [Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html#using-the-message-command).

Generate configuration file for the scanner:

```
./yii message/config-template your/path/to/saving/config.php
```

Adjust the newly created `config.php` to your needs.

Run the command:

```
./yii message path/to/config.php
```

Comment: I tried this but the problem with this is that since my translations are in the database it scans and outputs a file with all instances of the Yii::t(...) function but does not differentiate between the ones that I have already translated or the ones I have not translated yet... And in the documentation it does not mention how to confirgure the message command for the scenario where I use DBMessageSource.... Is there any other way to get this done???

Comment: If you generate config using `message/config-template` there is the part for `db` at the bottom commented (starts with `// 'db' output format is for saving messages to database.`). Use this in configuration.